# Carbon fork crack?

Tags: road-bike, fork, carbon, aluminum, crack

I have aluminum bike with carbon fork, this is in the front of the carbon fork, it is in both sides of it?
It's a carbon crack or paint crack?
[image]

Comment: I would say paint.

Comment: Is it really carbon? The sharp contours of the hole in the top left of the photo look a lot like metal.

Comment: Check with a slight tap with the side of a screwdriver. Carbon sounds dull and hollow.